# Scroll when hover arrow - like amazon website

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, react-hooks

Have you guys seen the dropdown from Amazon, when you hover on the arrow at the bottom it scrolls like using the wheel from the mouse. How can I achieve the same effect using css and react in general terms?

Any suggestion?
This is my code so far, but right now only the button is scrolling not all the menu.

```
 return (
      <div className="menu-wrapper">
        <div>
          <a className="menu-item">Pizza</a>
          <a className="menu-item">Hamburguers</a>
          <a className="menu-item">Guacamole</a>
          <a className="menu-item">Sushi</a>
          <button className="scroll-button-down">{"⌄"}</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    );

css

  .scroll-button-down:hover {
    animation: moveMenushow 0.6s linear forwards;
  }

  @keyframes moveMenushow {
    100% {
      transform: translateY(-40%);
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is just a "masked" `<select>` tag. The scrolling is built-in to browsers and will happen when the number of options exceeds the height of the viewport.

There are multiple ways of making custom-designed dropdowns, including [a fully custom solution](https://moderncss.dev/custom-select-styles-with-pure-css/), but the easiest way, and the way that Amazon is doing it is by overlaying an element on top of a `<select>` tag with pointer-events disabled so your click passes through to trigger the `<select>` tag's native dropdown implementation.

From there you can store the `<select>` tag's value with `onChange` and `useState` and then tie the "All" text in the overlay to that state variable.

Here's an example of the CSS:

```css
label {
  position:relative;
  display:block;
  width:max-content;
}

span {
  display:block;
  pointer-events:none;
  background:yellow;
  border-top-left-radius:20px;
  border-bottom-left-radius:20px;
  position:relative;
  z-index:1;
  padding:.25em 1.75em .25em 1em;
}

span::after {
  content:"";
  position:absolute;
  top:50%;
  right:10px;
  transform:translateY(-50%);
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 5px 5px 0 5px;
  border-color: #000000 transparent transparent transparent;
}

select {
  cursor:pointer;
  position:absolute;
  top:0;
  left:0;
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
  background:red;
  opacity:0;
}
```

```html
<label class="select-wrapper">
  <span> All</span>
  <select>
    <option>Red</option>
    <option>Green</option>
    <option>Blue</option>
  </select>
</label>
```

Comment: Thanks for the response @Riley, but what about the scroll? I would like to know how is working when we hover the caret down...

Comment: It's literally just a built-in browser feature. As soon as the dropdown gets too long to display all the options, the scrolling becomes available. If you'd like to implement something like that but outside of the context of a `<select>` tag, you could rearrange your HTML so the button comes first, then use a sibling selector with the hover to apply an animation to another element. `button:hover + ul { animation: moveMenuShow 1s; }` but it will require a bunch of additional CSS.

Comment: Gotcha!! In that case, I will change the div element for a select element. Thanks peer! @Riley

Comment: The native implementation is much better for accessibility as well. To do things entirely properly with a custom version that supports screen readers, you'd have to manage keyboard focus and handle ARIA states, in addition to implementing all the handlers in React as well. A good general tip is that you would only want to use an `<a>` tag to navigate to a different page in your app/site.